# Can the flash player play .wav files from a url?

Tags: flash

Let's say I have a wav file at a url:

```
http://hostname.com/mysound.wav
```

I'm trying to load the wav file with the sound class like:

```
var url:String = "http://hostname.com/test.wav";
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.load(urlRequest);
sound.play();
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Can flash player play wav files, or is it just mp3s?

Comment: What codec is your wav encoded in?  Wav is a container, not a sound format.  It can contain raw, MP3, uLaw, and others.

Comment: The vast majority of wavs are raw though. And I don't think it matters in this case anyway. It's the container format that matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The ActionScript documentation for the Sound class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) states that only MP3 files are supported.

Comment: And perhaps that's for the best.

Comment: @aaaidan Not if you want to deal with high quality PCM.

Answer (score 9):

here a simple class for loading and playing wav files from a url in flash using the open source popforge library: http://code.google.com/p/popforge/

cheers!

```
    public class WavURLPlayer
     {


      public static function PlayWavFromURL(wavurl:String):void
      {
       var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoaderIOError);

       var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(wavurl);

       urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
      }

      private static function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
      {
       var urlLoader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
        urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        urlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoaderIOError);

       var wavformat:WavFormat = WavFormat.decode(urlLoader.data);

       SoundFactory.fromArray(wavformat.samples, wavformat.channels, wavformat.bits, wavformat.rate, onSoundFactoryComplete);
      }

      private static function onLoaderIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
      {
       var urlLoader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
        urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        urlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoaderIOError);

       trace("error loading sound");

      }

      private static function onSoundFactoryComplete(sound:Sound):void
      {
       sound.play();
      }


 }
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer as it accomplishes loading/playing a .wav from a URL. The accepted answer is just pointing out that the Sound class doesn't support loading a .wav from a url.

Answer (score 5):

Directly you cannot but there are workarounds thanks to the ByteArray ; )

**Check this out :**

http://richapps.de/?p=97

> EDIT:
>
> The previous link being a bit old I
>   reckon you should also have a look on
>   Andre and Joa's fabulous **PopForge**
>   library. There's actually a wav
>   decoder class there as well.
>
> http://code.google.com/p/popforge/source/browse/#svn/trunk/flash/PopforgeLibrary/src/de/popforge/format/wav

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. I have made Wav/Au Flash player, that can play stream wav, encoded in G.711 or PCM in any bitlength and samplerate.
Licensed under GPLv2, here: http://blog.datacompboy.ru/2009/10/15/wav-au-flash-player/

Comment: Let me tell you something about this post. I've been seeking about an hour, quite tough to find universal solution. I SWEAR this is EXACTLY what you would need to play different small sound clips on your webpage with maximum browser compatibility and minimum load. It does EXACTLY what you expect, easy to test and embed. Get snapshot of the git code: http://git.datacompboy.ru/?p=WavPlayer.git;a=snapshot;h=b24cc6500058ec35c95953095c797865488416dd;sf=tgz then just put in web dir. Create your gsm encoded WAV with Sound Recorder, put in the same dir as tinyembed.html to see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

Flash itself does not support playing .wav files. Flash/Flex Builder compiles it directly into a Sound object ready to be played in your scripts, but for external .wav sound, the Flash SDK won't help you.

You will need to read the .wav data yourself and make Flash play, or: there are a couple of third-party libraries around that do this for you. The above post uses popforge, here's tutorial that demonstrates as3wavsound playing an external .wav file from a URL:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/media/quick-tip-play-external-wav-files-in-as3/