# Playing a sound in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play a wav file by ANY means. With the audio tag or not, it does not matter.

It's for an application only used internally, and the sound only plays when a serious error is made. So it exists to annoy people.

This is the code so far:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'wav/actors_relig1.wav');
audioElement.play();
```

But that did not work.

Comment: your code is correct, but check is the src (file path) is correct?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700300/embedd-wav-files-in-html-page-in-all-browsers-no-controls

Comment: Even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187098/cross-platform-cross-browser-way-to-play-sound-from-javascript

Comment: And another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep

Comment: In other words, plenty of examples to be found on stackoverflow. So do a search! ;oP

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to append the created div first

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(audioElement);`

and wait for it to load with

`audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {audioElement.play()}, false);`

Comment: i am not really sure if it is `loadeddata` or not but i know for sure about `loadedmetadata` (which fires when, as the name suggests, meta data of the audio is loaded but song itself is not) so `loadeddata` makes sense, a quick google search didn't reveal anything but it should work :)