# How to play wave file using http?

Tags: flash, audio, wav

How can I play wave file using flash?

I'm able to play mp3 files using the following code.

```
<embed id="wmp" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" EnableContextMenu="false" autostart="true" width="320" height="240" loop="false"
src=<%= request.getParameter("url") %> />
```

Comment: This, as it stands, is not a real question. You may as well ask "How do I make a cake with a bicycle" ? Please rephrase it. I think your question is probably to do with HTML applications and web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Not shore if wave formated audio is supported in adobe flash.
Wikipedia does not mention support for wave audio http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#Flash_Audio

Edit:
found this answer on the topic. (how to play wav audio in flash) [Can the flash player play .wav files from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668186/can-the-flash-player-play-wav-files-from-a-url)

According to that article wav audio is not natively suppported by flash but their is some workarounds