# Is it possible to play a 10khz wav file in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Hi guys i want to play a wav file in Flex. The sound has a sample rate of 10khz. can we play that file? And i want to know one more thing please suggest a good wav decoder in AS3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the flash player play .wav files from a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668186/can-the-flash-player-play-wav-files-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a codec to play the wav file.  The only thing built into the Flash Player is mp3 support.  I am not aware of an AS3 wav codec, so you'll have to write your own to make this happen.  It is possible, but I'm not sure how trivial it is.