# error in playing a sound in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript

When I play the movie, there wasn't any compile error, but the sound doesn't play,
Here is my code in ActionScript 3.0, any help is much appreciated..

```
     if (Total==Number(Number1.text)) {
         Count=Count+10;
         count_txt.text=Count.toString();
         var Snd:Sound=new Sound();
         var req:URLRequest=(new URLRequest("right.wav"));
         Snd.load(req);
         }break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that Flash cannot play WAV files - only MP3.

See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668186/can-the-flash-player-play-wav-files-from-a-url) which explains how to work around this issue and play WAV files.

Good luck!